# Strange SQL-Statement

Tags: sql

I just found an SQL-Statement with a syntax I never seen before. And I found nothing in the internet about this syntax. Does anybody knows what [field] means?

```
SELECT 'Customer' AS Tablename
, [Ct_ID] AS ID
, [Ct_Name] AS Name
FROM Customer
```

Comment: ?, it's just the name of the column. In SQL Server, you can use `[]` to wrap the name, and is needed when using spaces and other special chars

Comment: They are used by SQL Server for delimited identifiers. ANSI SQL has double quotes instead, like `"Ct_ID"` - which is also supported by SQL Server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In MS TransactSQL (aka SQL Server), square brackets are used around field names that would otherwise not be valid (reserved words, names with spaces or other special characters).

Comment: `MS TransactSQL (aka SQL Server)`....SQL Server is the name of the database engine, Transact-SQL is the name of the particular implementation of the language. They are not the same thing

Comment: I know they are not the same thing. And yet many people searching for Transact-SQL syntax use a format similar to "In SQL Server ,how do I..."

Answer (score 0):

What is strange about this syntax?  The square braces are used by some databases as escape characters.  They are not needed here.  This query returns three columns.  The placement of commas at the beginning of a line is a style, which I as a human being who reads languages with commas, do not agree with.

I would write it without the escapes:

```
SELECT 'Customer' AS Tablename, Ct_ID AS ID, Ct_Name AS Name
FROM Customer;
```

Comment: I called it strange because I never saw this after years of sql usage.

Answer (score 0):

It is a field... really. Optional but the way to refer a field if for example it has a space in the name.

Comment: I know that this are fields. But I normally use MySQL and not MSSQL. And MySQL uses an other syntax for this.